# Laravel encoded with Zend Guard displays blade view text in browser

Tags: php, laravel-5, zend-guard

Have a Laravel project that I encoded with Zend Guard.

When I run the application, it is getting to the right route, but it displays the text of my view file in the browser rather than rendering the view.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Is there a certain way to encode Laravel projects in what should and should not be encoded?

Comment: The correct solution is not include the files that have problem. It's because some script need pre render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, the only "solution" that I found was to avoid encrypt those file with "*.blade.php" extension

Comment: Can you share more info about your solution?